# ${name} not returning the input in node.js

Tags: node.js

So, I'm fairly new to node.js, but do have some experience with various languages.  Nothing in production, but mostly academic.  Right now I am just testing out various code snippets in node.js using VS Code.  See the code snippet below.  When it runs in the VS Code terminal, it returns hello, ${name}, rather than the names entered in the greet() function.  Is it something I'm missing in settings, the code or an issue with vs code?

---

```
const greet = (name) =>{
  console.log('hello, ${name}');
};

greet('mario');
greet('yoshi');
```

---

App Versions:

VS Code: 1.87.0
Electron:  27.3.2
ElectronBuildID: 26836302
Chromium:  118.0.5993.159
Node.js 18.17.1
V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
OS:  Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

I was hoping the input I put in the greet() function would return upon output.  Instead, it return "hello, ${name}.  I've noticed that the ${} has not worked previously with other code testing I've done.

Comment: you didn't use template literals.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested, you're not using [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) backtick ` in the script instead using the single quoted character. Hence it should be

```js
const greet = (name) => { console.log(`hello, ${name}`); };
```

instead of

```js
const greet = (name) => { console.log('hello, ${name}'); };
```